# $\mathcal P(\omega)\in L_\alpha$

Tags: set-theory

Assuming the V=L axiom, what's the smallest $\alpha$ such that $\mathcal P(\omega)∈L_\alpha$? (Notation from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_universe).)

(Remember that V=L implies the continuum hypothesis.)

Also, if anyone can explain the $\models$ notation used in the article (or provide a link to an explanation), that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The smallest is $\omega_1+1$. By a condensation argument (see the proof of CH in L) it follows that every  subset $A 
\subseteq \omega$ is in some $L_{\alpha}$ for $\alpha$ countable. Thus $\mathcal{P}(\omega)$ is definable over $L_{\omega_1}$.

Comment: Does this mean that $\mathcal P(\omega)\subset L_{\omega_1}$?

Comment: @columbus8myhw: Yes, since if $A\subseteq\omega$, then there is some $\alpha<\omega_1$ such that $A\in L_\alpha$, and since the $L_\xi$'s is an increasing hierarchy, $L_\alpha\subseteq L_{\omega_1}$.